# elixir recursion block not returning proper value

Tags: elixir

I want the following block of code to return value not equal to 0 or n. But sometimes it returns values equal to 0.

```
def get_random(n, num) do   
   random = returns some number
   IO.puts random
   if random == n or random == 0 do
      get_random(n, num)
   end
   random
end
```

Comment: shouldn't it be ```random``` instead of ```ran``` in your if statement?

Comment: I have changed the variable name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `random` variable second time.

Fixed code:

```
defmodule GetRandom do
  def get_random(n, num) do
    random = Enum.random(0..num)
    IO.puts random
    random = if random == n or random == 0 do
      get_random(n, num)
    else
      random
    end
    random
  end
end
```

This code can be simplified. First, if `Enum.random` is used, you don't need to exclude `0` after call. Just exclude it from range.

Also, use implicit value return. You don't need to set `random` variable second time if it is in the end of the function.

```
defmodule GetRandom do
  def get_random(n, num) do
    random = Enum.random(1..num)
    IO.puts random
    if random == n do
      get_random(n, num)
    else
      random
    end
  end
end
```